# Rounding numbers to nearest multiple of 5 or 10 in the same range depending on what's first

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm working on a statistics app and I have an issue with rounding.
I want to display a chart that has multiple point all connected to lines.
To be able to adjust the scale automatically I want to perform some kind of calculation. I've figured out what to do, but I can't translate it properly to code.

So here's what I want to do:
I look through my list of values to find the largest value.
In my graphic I have 6 reference lines. So I divide my value by one-less-than-the-amount-of-positions to make sure I get a value which (when multiplied by the actual number of positions) will be larger then my largest amount, so that my line doesn't go outside of my graphic.

Once i have this value, I would need to get the nearest integer of 5 or 10 (depending what comes first) in the same range.

So to give you some examples:

```
example 1:
initial value = 685425
divided value = 685425/5 = 137085 => rounded value = 150000

example 2:
initial value = 53
divided value = 53/5 = 10.6 => rounded value = 15

example 3:
initial value = 8215
divided value = 8215/5 = 1643 => rounded value = 2000
```

So I'm always rounding up to the nearest multiple of 5 or 10 but in the same range.

How can I put this in code?

Thank you,
Kenneth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int GetLimit(int v)
{
    int by5 = v / 5;

    // for too small numbers we return early
    if (by5 < 0) return 0;
    if (by5 < 5) return 5;
    if (by5 < 10) return 10;

    int log = (int)Math.Log10(by5) - 1;
    int scope = (int)Math.Pow(10, log);
    int tmp = by5 / scope;
    tmp = 5 * ((tmp/5) + 1);
    return tmp * scope;
}
```

This uses the decimal logarithm to get the "range" (`scope`). Then it divides the number by that scope to get the first two digits, "rounds" them to the next multiple of 5 (`5*((tmp/5) + 1)`) and multiplies by the scope again to get back to the range.

For too small numbers (below 50) it returns early, because `scope` would become `0` which would lead to an `DivideByZeroException`.

```
Console.WriteLine(GetLimit(685425));
Console.WriteLine(GetLimit(53));
Console.WriteLine(GetLimit(8215));
Console.WriteLine(GetLimit(11));
Console.WriteLine(GetLimit(2));
```

results in

```
150000
15
2000
5
5
```

---

An alternative to using `Math.Log` and `Math.Pow` would be to convert the divided number to a string work with thefirst two digits and the length. I did not test if this could be faster, but I don't think so. If this is performance critical you'd need to test it.